# What does it mean "The antiforgery token could not be decrypted." and how to fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I'm creating a Asp.net core image along Postgresql image using docker orchestator container. But when I test the create function. Return me the following error message:

```
 "The antiforgery token could not be decrypted."
```

I was trying to create data and record it in a postgresql database. But I dont know the error it might be.

This is the `CreateStudent` function:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,FirstName,LastName,Email")] Student student)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(student);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(student);
        }
```

And this this is the create.cshtml

```
`
@model _netcoreApi.Models.Student

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Registro</h1>

<h4>Estudiante</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>`
```

If anyone could help me or bring me some help

Comment: The code your provided is working well, could you share more details about how to test the Create post method ?

Comment: I tried to create a new student and when I send data from view to database, return me the message  "The antiforgery token could not be decrypted."

Comment: Pls set breakpoint and share more details, which line return this error.